# Highlighting lines on QTextEdit document

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, highlight, qtextedit

Attempting to create a way (using PyQt5 and Python 3) to highlight a given line number in the document of the QTextEdit widget. Here is the attempted code below (with many thanks to those in stackoverflow who answered similar questions before):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextBlockFormat, QTextBlock, QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout

sample = """
Test document...
This is Line 2
This is Line 3
Explanation:
  This is an explanation section. Here we explain.
  Explanation section ends.
Back to body of document.
This is Line 8.
This is the last line.
"""


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.editor = QTextEdit(self)
        self.editor.setText(sample)

        self.format_normal = QTextBlockFormat()
        self.format_normal.setBackground(Qt.white)

        self.highlight_format = QTextBlockFormat()
        self.highlight_format.setBackground(Qt.yellow)

        self.cursor = self.editor.textCursor()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.editor)

    def setLineFormat(self, lineNumber, format):
        """ Sets the highlighting of a given line number in the QTextEdit"""
        #self.cursor.clearSelection()
        self.cursor.select(QTextCursor.Document)
        self.cursor.setBlockFormat(self.format_normal)

        self.cursor = QTextCursor(self.editor.document().findBlockByNumber(lineNumber))
        self.cursor.setBlockFormat(format)

    def cycle_through_lines(self):
        """ Cycles through specified lines. """
        for ii in range(2, 8):
            self.setLineFormat(ii, self.highlight_format)
            self.pause(1000)

    def pause(self, duration):
        """ Provides a pause of a specified duration. """
        loop = QEventLoop()
        QTimer.singleShot(duration, loop.quit)
        loop.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 150, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    window.cycle_through_lines()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Question(s):

- Why is there no need to instantiate a new cursor to select the entirety of the document (when resetting the highlighting), but when a single line needs to be selected, a new instance of the QTextCursor() needs to be created?
- Is there a way to select a single line without creating a new instance?
- Would this approach create any memory issues if the document is long and a large number of lines need to be selected?

Presumably the garbage collector would handle this issue, but I just wanted to learn the details behind the curtain a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Why is there no need to instantiate a new cursor to select the entirety of the document (when resetting the highlighting), but when a single line needs to be selected, a new instance of the QTextCursor() needs to be created?

  Because selecting the entire document does not require having special information unlike selecting a line, word, etc. So that any QTextCursor obtained from the QTextEdit (more precisely any QTextCursor from the QTextDocument associated with the QTextEdit) will allow you to select the entire document.
- Is there a way to select a single line without creating a new instance?

  To select a line is necessary that the QTextCursor has special information such as the start and end of the line, so you must build a QTextCursor based on the QTextBlock.
- Would this approach create any memory issues if the document is long and a large number of lines need to be selected?

  No, a memory issue is not created since in your case you assign it to the same object, but I still prefer to use the following method

  ```
  def setLineFormat(self, lineNumber, format):
      """ Sets the highlighting of a given line number in the QTextEdit"""
      cursor = self.editor.textCursor()
      cursor.select(QTextCursor.Document)
      cursor.setBlockFormat(self.format_normal)
  ```

  cursor = QTextCursor(self.editor.document().findBlockByNumber(lineNumber))
      cursor.setBlockFormat(format)

  With my method the QTextCursor are local variables that will be eliminated when the method is finished executing.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the clarifications.